# Facebook Error with Open Graph event. "has an empty title and description"

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, title

I have an error message in my activity log:

> This story was invalidated because: The object at
>   https://asperia.srv3.shapeshifters.ru/social/facebook.com/objects/object.php?type=quest&id=108&fb_source=timeline_og
>   has an empty title and description but is missing a user generated
>   photo.

But I'm sure that object is alright. You can see all field here in object debug screen: [image: http://puu.sh/3hMax.png]
Title and description are filled.

And more. `but is missing a user generated photo.` - I cant understand this. What photo? Story does not working with "user generated foto".

Comment: What call are you using for the story (specifically with code)

Comment: code: 
Facebook.api("me/myth_guardians:complete", onObjectActionComplete, {quest: "https://asperia.srv3.shapeshifters.ru/social/facebook.com/objects/object.php?type=quest&id=" + String(quest.id)}, "POST");

Comment: and its good for all others types of OG Object Types (no errors) except "quest".